# jQuery tabs html: hiding and showing corresponding paragraphs

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="headings">
  <h1 class="one seleced"><a href="#">One</a></h1>
  <h1 class="two"><a href="#">Two</a></h1>
  <h1 class="three"><a href"#">Three</a></h1>
</div>
<div class="paragraphs">
  <p class="one">Hello One</p>
  <p class="two">Hello Two</p>
  <p class="three">Hello Three</p>
</div>
```

(or something similar). I want to set up a jQuery function with these objectives in mind:

1. When the document loads all paragraphs except for the ones corresponding
   to selected heading are hidden. Thus at the beginning this will be all
   but paragraph one, but I would like the code to be generic so that if I
   add another heading and paragraph I won't have to change any jQuery code.

2a. When heading foo is clicked, the "selected" class is applied to all but
   heading foo, so that only heading foo has a class of "selected" which via
   css is used to style the foo element accordingly.

2b. When heading foo (say number two) is clicked, only the corresponding
   paragraph becomes visible (in this case paragraph two).

I want something like:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".headings a").onClick(function() {
      $this.addClass("selected");
      others().removeClass("selected");
    }

    var selectionIndex = $(".headings").nForChildWithClass("selected");
    $(".paragraphs").not(childAtIndex("n")).hide();
    $(".paragraphs").(childAtIndex("n")).show();

  });
```

Thank you for your input on how to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `h1's` index to target the corresponding paragraph:

```
$('div.headings > h1').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this), idx = $this.index();
    $this.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $('div.paragraphs > p').eq(idx).show().siblings().hide();
}).eq(0).click();
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QNgxf/)

Answer (score 1):

I would change the HTML slightly.

```
<div class="headings">
  <h1 data-num="one" class="seleced"><a>One</a></h1>
  <h1 data-num="two"><a>Two</a></h1>
  <h1 data-num="three"><a>Three</a></h1>
</div>
```

Then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  showSelected();
  $("h1").click(function() {
    $("h1.selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    showSelected();
  });
});

function showSelected() {
  var show = $(".selected").data("num");
  $("p").hide();
  $("."+show).show();
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hM26j/

(Note that I changed the spelling of 'selected' in the headings.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('h1.selected').each(function() {
  var this_class_notselect = $(this).attr('class');
  this_class_notselect = this_class_notselect.replace("selected", "");
  $('p').hide();
  $('p.'+this_class_notselect).show();
 });
 $('h1').on('click', function() {
  var this_class = $(this).attr('class');
  $('h1').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('p').hide();
  $('p.'+this_class).show();
 });
});
```

This code should do it, it can be enhanced tho.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple one, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/b5Sde/

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.paragraphs p.'+$('h1.selected a').attr('target')).show();
    $('.headings h1 a').on('click', function(){
        $('.paragraphs p').hide();
        $('.paragraphs p.'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
    });
});
```